# How can I format a document for submission to Analysis journal?

Tags: formatting

I am preparing a paper for submission to the journal, Analysis, which doesn't have a ready-made latex template.

Here's an example of what their documents look like:

[image]

In particular, I'm interested in: (1) which font I should use; (2) how to get the title and author left aligned and in that particular style; and (3) how to get the title and page number as they are in the picture (see top right).

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to do this to submit a paper to them at all. If your paper looks like this, they'll toss it back to you unread because it is not prepared for triple-blind review, which Analysis uses. In fact, you don't need to do it even if your paper is accepted. They'll do this stuff, if they want it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer to the question I think you should have asked ...

If the journal doesn't give you style files I suggest just vanilla arrticle class. If the paper is accepted they will format it. If not, you haven't cluttered it with formatting some other journal won't like.